# Modifying Robolectric's Instrumentation Configuration with AndroidX Tests

Tags: android, junit, android-testing, androidx, robolectric

I use a custom Robolectric Test Runner in my app that changes the `InstrumentationConfiguration` as follows -

```
public class MyTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {
    public MyTestRunner(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
        super(klass);
    }

    @Override
    public InstrumentationConfiguration createClassLoaderConfig(final FrameworkMethod method) {
        InstrumentationConfiguration.Builder builder = new InstrumentationConfiguration.Builder(super.createClassLoaderConfig(method));
        builder.addInstrumentedPackage("net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase");
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

I am migrating my Robolectric tests to use Android X test APIs and run them with `AndroidJUnit4` rather than `MyTestRunner`. According to [Robolectric docs](http://robolectric.org/androidx_test/), I can use the [configuration and plugin API](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/4.2/org/robolectric/pluginapi/package-summary.html) instead of a custom test runner though I don't see any extension points through which I can change the `InstrumentationConfiguration`. Does anyone here can help out in how can I edit my `InstrumentationConfiguration` in AndroidX world ?

Answer (score 0):

you can add to you instrumentationConfiguration like following:

```
@Override
@Nonnull
protected InstrumentationConfiguration createClassLoaderConfig(final FrameworkMethod method) {
    Config config = configuration.get(Config.class);
    InstrumentationConfiguration.Builder builder = new InstrumentationConfiguration.Builder(super.createClassLoaderConfig(method));
    androidConfigurer.configure(builder, getInterceptors());
    androidConfigurer.withConfig(builder, config);
    for (String s : CUSTOM_INSTRUMENTED_CLASS_NAME) {
        builder.addInstrumentedClass(s);
    }
    return builder.build();
}
```

here *CUSTOM_INSTRUMENTED_CLASS_NAME* is an String array of class names: ex:

```
String[] CUSTOM_INSTRUMENTED_CLASS_NAME = {
            foo.class.getName(),
            bar.class.getName()
}
```